# Find paths between nodes in JS object graph

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, graph-theory

How can I get this result:

```
[
  {Paris,Amsterdam,Berlin},
  {Paris,Bruxelles,Amsterdam,Berlin},
  {Paris,Bruxelles,Berlin}
]
```

from this array:

```
[
  { HD: '9:20', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '3:20' },
  { HD: '8:30', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Bruxelles', D: '1:20' },
  { HD: '10:00', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '2:10' },
  { HD: '12:30', V1: 'Amsterdam', V2: 'Berlin', D: '6:10' },
  { HD: '11:30', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Berlin', D: '9:20' } 
]
```

I want to map data from this array to get all the possibilities of paths to get from a city to another, from 'Paris' To 'Berlin' for example.

Comment: You cannot. Each object is composed by a key and a value. You only have a key.

Comment: Is there another solution ? I can change the array format

Comment: Or how can i get this solution in node js ! and thank you for the response

Comment: I think the problem is the `{}` object syntax in your desired result is a typo. Did you mean `[]` (arrays)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = [
    {HD: '9:20', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '3:20'},
    {HD: '8:30', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Bruxelles', D: '1:20'},
    {HD: '10:00', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '2:10'},
    {HD: '12:30', V1: 'Amsterdam', V2: 'Berlin', D: '6:10'},
    {HD: '11:30', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Berlin', D: '9:20'}
];

function getDuration(hd, d) {
    let time1 = hd.split(":");
    let time2 = d.split(":");
    let h1 = parseInt(time1[0]);
    let m1 = parseInt(time1[1]);
    let h2 = parseInt(time2[0]);
    let m2 = parseInt(time2[1]);
    if (h2 < h1) {
        h2 += 12;
    }
    let time = (h2 * 60 + m2) - (h1 * 60 + m1);
    let offset = (time % 60) * 0.01;
    return Math.floor(time / 60) + offset;
}

let mapper = {};
let durations = {};

data.forEach(item => {
    if (!mapper[item.V1]) {
        mapper[item.V1] = [];
    }
    mapper[item.V1].push(item.V2);
    durations[item.V1 + "_" + item.V2] = getDuration(item.HD, item.D);
});

let generatedRoutes = [];

function routeGenerator(starting, destination, path) {
    if (starting === destination) {
        generatedRoutes.push(path);
        return;
    }
    if (!mapper[starting]) return;
    let routes = mapper[starting];
    routes.forEach(route => {
        routeGenerator(route, destination, path + "," + route);
    })
}

routeGenerator("Paris", "Berlin", "Paris");

function calculateTimeDuration() {
    let minDuration = 100000;
    let minDurationPath = "";
    generatedRoutes.forEach(path => {
        let paths = path.split(",");
        let d = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < paths.length - 1; i++) {
            let firstCity = paths[i];
            let secondCity = paths[i + 1];
            let key = firstCity + '_' + secondCity;
            d += durations[key];
        }
        if (d < minDuration) {
            minDuration = d;
            minDurationPath = path;
        }
    });
    return {
        duration: minDuration,
        path: minDurationPath
    }
}

console.log(calculateTimeDuration());
```

OK, It's a kinda graph problem to solve. First of all, you need to map all the routes you have starting from a certain V1. mapper objects contain every routes for a certain path.

then, just a normal recursive function to generate the routes.

Console Output:

```
{ 
    duration: 11.4,
    path: 'Paris,Amsterdam,Berlin'
}
```

I have generated the paths as string and you can split them if you need and pushed them into the array.

if you need to generate paths for any other entry point, you can do that. Just change the parameters passing through routeGenerator. For example, if you change it to,

`routeGenerator("Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Amsterdam");`

you will get:

```
{ 
    duration: 5.4,
    path: 'Amsterdam,Berlin'
}
```

Comment: Thank your very much for your answer it worked for me  ! 
But  i didn't understand : 
why when you call the function you need to pass parameter the same value and not :
routeGenerator("Paris", "Berlin");

Comment: first parameter is for starting position, and second one is keeping the previous path. So, when we go from one place to another, it will concat the route with the previous one to build the path. at a certain point, there will be no path go forward, then it push the generated path to the generatedRoutes list.

Comment: Okey thank you and it's possible to send the duration of  path into the result  ?  because i need  to send the information of every path ! 
i have to calculate the duration of every path 
And in the final give the shortest path duration and the arrival time

Comment: I think what you are looking for is shortest path in terms of time duration between a starting point to an destination point, right?

Comment: Exactly that's what i'm looking for

Comment: I have updated code. Please check if it is working as you expected.

Comment: It worked perfectly , Thank for much for your help and for spending time to answer me

Answer (score 6):

The input [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type))  is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) and looks like this:

```
  +-----------------------+
  |                       |
  |                       v
Paris -> Bruxelles -> Amsterdam -> Berlin
             |                       ^
             |                       |
             +-----------------------+
```

We can build an object with source strings mapped to an array of their possible destinations which is much more convenient to use than the input object, then run a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the graph and [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) each result path.

```js
function *findPaths(graph, src, dst, path=[]) {
  if (src === dst) {
    yield path.concat(dst);
  }
  else if (graph[src]) {
    path.push(src);
    
    for (const neighbor of graph[src]) {
      yield *findPaths(graph, neighbor, dst, path);
    }
    
    path.pop(src);
  }
};

const graphify = routes => {
  const graph = {};
  
  for (const node of routes) {
    if (!graph[node.V1]) {
      graph[node.V1] = [];
    }
    
    graph[node.V1].push(node.V2)
  }
  
  return graph;
};

const routes = [
  { HD: '9:20', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '3:20' },
  { HD: '8:30', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Bruxelles', D: '1:20' },
  { HD: '10:00', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '2:10' },
  { HD: '12:30', V1: 'Amsterdam', V2: 'Berlin', D: '6:10' },
  { HD: '11:30', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Berlin', D: '9:20' } 
];

console.log(...findPaths(graphify(routes), "Paris", "Berlin"));
```

If you anticipate cycles in your graph, add a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of visited nodes to avoid re-visiting them during a traversal:

```js
function *findPaths(graph, src, dst, path=[], visited=(new Set())) {
  if (src === dst) {
    yield path.concat(dst);
  }
  else if (graph[src] && !visited.has(src)) {
    visited.add(src);
    path.push(src);
    
    for (const neighbor of graph[src]) {
      yield *findPaths(graph, neighbor, dst, path, visited);
    }
    
    visited.delete(src);
    path.pop(src);
  }
};

const graphify = routes => {
  const graph = {};
  
  for (const node of routes) {
    if (!graph[node.V1]) {
      graph[node.V1] = [];
    }
    
    graph[node.V1].push(node.V2)
  }
  
  return graph;
};

const routes = [
  { HD: '9:20', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '3:20' },
  { HD: '8:30', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Bruxelles', D: '1:20' },
  { HD: '10:00', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '2:10' },
  { HD: '12:30', V1: 'Amsterdam', V2: 'Paris', D: '6:10' },
  { HD: '12:30', V1: 'Amsterdam', V2: 'Berlin', D: '6:10' },
  { HD: '11:30', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Berlin', D: '9:20' },
  { HD: '11:30', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Paris', D: '9:20' } 
];

console.log(...findPaths(graphify(routes), "Paris", "Berlin"));
```

If you wish to account for travel time (edge weights), use [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). The implementation is more involved because we need a priority queue (min/Fibonacci heap) to efficiently extract the shortest tentative distance.

Answer (score 0):

Without using map Function

> JS Seems to get confused with map in this case

```
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), obj[key]];
});
```

Here is a way using a for statement

```js
    var obj =    [
      { HD: '9:20', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '3:20' },
      { HD: '8:30', V1: 'Paris', V2: 'Bruxelles', D: '1:20' },
      { HD: '10:00', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Amsterdam', D: '2:10' },
      { HD: '12:30', V1: 'Amsterdam', V2: 'Berlin', D: '6:10' },
      { HD: '11:30', V1: 'Bruxelles', V2: 'Berlin', D: '9:20' }
    ]
    console.log(obj);
    let NewArray = [];
    for (i=0;i<obj.length ;i++){
         console.log(obj[i].HD);

        let HD = obj[i].HD;
        let V1 = obj[i].V1;
        let V2 = obj[i].V2;
        let D = obj[i].D;
        
        NewArray[i] = {HD,V1,V2,D};
    }
    console.log(NewArray);
```

Comment: The snippet does not actually show the requested format

Comment: Oh I didn't see the second section before answering .